# gcc ignores the -Wl,--dynamic-linker switch

Tags: gcc, linker, arm, cross-compiling, elf

I'm trying to make the --dynamic-linker option work with CodeSourcery's ARM cross toolchain. However gcc seems to ignore it, and never adds an interpreter segment in the shared library's ELF. What am I missing to make this work?

Comment: Can you please present the complete command line you are using?

Comment: Also, do you have an `.interp` instruction in your linker script?

Comment: @Martin: What is linker script and '.interp' instruction?

Comment: @Martin: I found out what linker script is, but it doesn't contain an .interp instruction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I doubt gcc ignores the option. Add `-v` to the compiler command line to verify that the option is indeed passed to the linker.

More likely, you are using the option incorrectly. `--dynamic-linker` is taking a `=file` argument, and you didn't mention that you are passing one.

**Edit**: as you found out, you have no .interp section in your linker script. However, you should - see [this example](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0474b/DHCCFGFG.html).

Comment: Thanks for trying to help. Unfortunately the switch reaches the linker. I have another -rpath switch that goes to the binary successfully, but the --dynamic-linker fails. Edit: and yes, I'm passing the "file" part too, otherwise the command doesn't execute

Comment: I think the question is then phrased confusingly: gcc does *not* ignore the flag; it's the linker which apparently fails to process it.